# How to focus a control that is inside a FormArray?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `FormArray` with an email field and I need to focus the field whenever a new control is added inside `FormArray` for the user to type the email.

I tried with `@ViewChild` but it doesn't work correctly as it will repeat the elements with the same id `#emailInput`.

**component.ts**

```
  public addEmail(): void {
    this.emailArray.push(this.createControlEmail());
    // Here I need to focus on the control that has been added.
    this.form.markAsDirty();
  }
```

**component.html**

```
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="start"
                        [formGroupName]="indexControlEmail">

                        <mat-form-field fxFlex="60" [floatLabel]="true">
                            <input #emailInput matInput placeholder="E-mail" formControlName="email">
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <button mat-icon-button aria-label="delete" matTooltip="Remove email"
                            [matTooltipPosition]="'after'" [matTooltipShowDelay]="1000"
                            (click)="removeEmail(indexControlEmail)">
                            <mat-icon class="secondary-text">close</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) to get list of email inputs on page.

> Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list
>   will be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will
>   emit a new value.

```
@ViewChildren('emailInput') emailInputs:  QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

Each time you do `addEmail` focus on last emailInput:

```
addEmail() {
    this.emailInputs.changes.pipe(take(1)).subscribe({
      next: changes => changes.last.nativeElement.focus()
    });
    this.emailArray.push(this.createControlEmail());
    // const newControl = this.fb.control('');
    // this.emailArray.push(newControl);
  }
```